# wrong display after deleting record

Tags: php

I use this code to trigger the row delete:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='$.get("web_page.php",{ cmd: "delete_stmt", id_f: "<?php echo $rrows['id_f']; ?>", id: "<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" } ,self.location="web_page.php");'>delete</a>
```

and this is the code:

```
if($get['cmd'] == 'delete_stmt') {
        $stmt = $conn_bd->prepare("DELETE FROM table WHERE id_f=:id_f and id=:id");
        $stmt->execute(array('id_f' => $get[id_f], 'id' => $get[id]));
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

the record is always deleted from the database table, but sometimes the record is displayed on the web page.
this happens in IE, Firefox, Chrome ...

do you have an idea what could be causing this?

thk

Comment: Your code is very hard to read without some linebreaks.

Comment: What exactly is displayed on the web page? In your example, you are missing a closing `'` but that should break the code *every* time

Comment: What is up with the `$get[]`?  Surely you mean to use `$_GET[]`.  Also, beware with deletion links. Make sure that the user deleting them has permission/ownership over them.

Comment: note that yhou're abusing php syntax. `$get[id_f]` should be `$get['id_f']`. php will normally politely treat that undefined constant as a string, and issue a warning. since you're not complaining about warnings, you've probably got error_reporting/display_errors turned off.

Comment: `self.location = "web_page.php"` executes *before* the `$.get()` call finishes. Throw the inline click handler away, bind it through event delegation instead, and execute the location change in the success callback for `$.get()`. And in general, don't perform any state-changing actions through GET, always use POST with CSRF tokens.

Comment: sorry, the record that I previously deleted is still displayed

Comment: it could be a browser cache problem?

Comment: @Marc B: yes, the error_reporting is turned off; i have some "undefined variable" messages, but none related to the delete statement. inconsistent behavior may be caused by those errors?

Comment: "*i have some "undefined variable" messages*" -- and those don't bother you??

Comment: @Dcoder - they are on my "to do list", but since none of them is related to the behavior of the delete statement, I treated them as separate issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your link to this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick='deleteItem("<?php echo $row['id_f']; ?>", "<?php echo $row['id']; ?>");'>delete</a>
```

... and add this function:

```
function deleteItem(row_id_f, row_id)
{
    $.get(
            "web_page.php",
            { cmd: "delete_stmt", id_f: row_id_f, id: row_id },
            function(data){

                self.location="web_page.php";

            }
        );
}
```

The link will call the deleteItem function which does the ajax call, it then waits for the success event before doing the page redirect.

Answer (score 0):

self.location executing before the $.get() call.  Try to create a function and wait for the $.get().

You can use the jquery ajax [Here is a official page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function. It is easy to use.  Also If you redirecting this own page, you can try hiding the "delete" and throw a alert box.